# Choosing the most suitable timestamp for event while inserting data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table in mysql that contains three columns:

```
     |  event_id  |  event_timestamp  |  event_duration  |
```

and now I want to write a part of php code that will insert new event as soon as there's a free time for that and the event fits the free slot.

Basically when user decides to add some event, the algorithm checks when (during the next half hour) is the next free time slot for that event and when it finds a time for that - adds it to the database with right timestamp.
Each event has its own duration, so we need to check the timeframe based on that.

I thought about writing the following SELECT query:

```
select id, timestamp, duration 
from table 
where timestamp >= 'begin-boundary-time' 
    and timestamp + duration <= 'end-boundary-time'
```

and then iterate through selected results in the php code until I find a free slot - and when I do, I will just do INSERT query there, but that's the part where I stuck. The basic code that I've written so far looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, timestamp, duration FROM table
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) >= NOW() 
      AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)+duration) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - timestamp: ". $row["timestamp"]. " " . $row["duration"] . "<br>";
//here I thought about processing data and putting INSERT query
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Does anyone know how to help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

My example selects all events (from table Events (id, start, duration)), behind which there is sufficient free time for a new record and calculate Next, and Delta values.
Next - start time for nearest next event.
Delta - unused time after event end (if null then unlimited)

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT e1.id, e1.start, e1.duration, e1.start+e1.duration as end, 
        (SELECT min(e2.start) as next from events as e2 
        where e2.start > e1.start+e1.duration) as next,
        (SELECT min(e3.start)-e1.start-e1.duration as delta from events as e3 
        where e3.start > e1.start+e1.duration) as delta
    FROM events e1) t
WHERE delta >= $yourDuration OR delta is null
```